# Check if any part of a string input is not a number

Tags: java

I couldnt find an answer for this in Java, so I'll ask here. I need to check if 3 parts of a string input contains a number (int).

The input will be HOURS:MINUTES:SECONDS (E.g. 10:40:50, which will be 10 hours, 40 minutes and 50 seconds). So far I am getting the values in String[] into an array by splitting it on :. I have parsed the strings into ints and I am using an if statement to check if all 3 parts is equal or larger than 0. The problem is that if I now use letters I will only just get an error, but I want to check if any of the 3 parts contains a character that is not 0-9, but dont know how.

First I thought something like this could work, but really dont.

```
String[] inputString = input.split(":");

if(inputString.length == 3) {
  String[] alphabet = {"a","b","c"};
  if(ArrayUtils.contains(alphabet,input)){
    gives error message
  }
  int hoursInt = Integer.parseInt(inputString[0]);
  int minutesInt = Integer.parseInt(inputString[1]);
  int secondsInt = Integer.parseInt(inputString[2]);
  else if(hoursInt >= 0 || minutesInt >= 0 || secondsInt >= 0) {
    successfull
  }
  else {
    gives error message
  }
else {
  gives error message
}
```

In the end I just want to check if any of the three parts contains a character, and if it doesnt, run something.

Comment: By definition, if you can parse the `String` to an `int` then it *does **not*** contain any non-digit characters. You would get a `NumberFormatException` if the text is not a legal integer value (so you could use try-catch). You could also use a regular expression like `if (inputString[0].matches("\\d+"))` to test that a given `String` is all digits. For a **robust** solution you may want to combine the two; a value could be all digits and overflow an `int`. Also, can any field exceed it's normal limit (e.g. 65 seconds)? What about negative values?

Comment: Are you trying to check whether three Strings consist of numbers or are you trying to parse a time string?

Comment: I am trying to check if all the strings in the array inputString only contains numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally create my own helper methods for this, instead of using an external library such as Apache (unless you already plan on using the library elsewhere in the project).

Here is an example of what it could look like:

```
public static void main(String[] arguments) {
    String time = "10:50:45";
    String [] arr = time.split(":");

    if (containsNumbers(arr)) {
        System.out.println("Time contained a number!");
    } 
    //You can put an else if you want something to happen when it is not a number
}

private static boolean containsNumbers(String[] arr) {
    for (String s : arr) {
        if (!isNumeric(s)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
    return str.matches("-?\\d+(.\\d+)?");
}
```

`containsNumbers` will take a `String` array as an input and use an enhanced `for` loop to iterate through all the `String` values, using the other helper method `isNumeric` that checks if the `String` is a number or not using `regex`.

This code has the benefit of not being dependent on `Exceptions` to handle any of the logic.

You can also modify this code to use a `String` as a parameter instead of an array, and let it handle the `split` inside of the method instead of outside.

Note that typically there are better ways to work with date and time, but I thought I would answer your literal question.

**Example Runs:**

```
String time = "sd:fe:gbdf";
returns false

String time = "as:12:sda";
returns false

String time = "10:50:45";
returns true
```

Answer (score 3):

**If you are sure you always have to parse a `String` of the form/pattern `HH:mm:ss`

(describing a time of day),**
you can try to parse it to a `LocalTime`, which will only work if the parts `HH`, `mm` and `ss` are actually valid integers **and** valid time values.

Do it like this and maybe catch an `Exception` for a wrong input `String`:

```
public static void main(String[] arguments) {
    String input = "10:40:50";
    String wrongInput = "ab:cd:ef";
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(input);
    System.out.println(time.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME));

    try {
        LocalTime t = LocalTime.parse(wrongInput);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpE) {
        System.err.println("Input not parseable...");
        dtpE.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The output of this minimal example is

```
10:40:50
Input not parseable...
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'ab:cd:ef' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalTime.parse(LocalTime.java:441)
    at java.time.LocalTime.parse(LocalTime.java:426)
    at de.os.prodefacto.StackoverflowDemo.main(StackoverflowDemo.java:120)
```

Comment: This will fail on `9:28:17`, but I do assume it's what OP actually wants.

Comment: @daniu yes, you are right, it will fail, but your example wouldn't be of the pattern `HH:mm:ss`. OP should check several patterns...

Answer (score 1):

You can check the stream of characters.

- If the filter does not detect a non-digit, return "Numeric"
- Otherwise, return "Not Numeric"

```
    String str = "922029202s9202920290220";
        String result = str.chars()
                .filter(c -> !Character.isDigit(c))
                .findFirst().isEmpty() ? "Numeric"
                        : "Not Numeric";

        System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Just as an aside, `isEmpty()` in this case will require Java11+ correct?

Comment: Yes.  That could probably be left off and come up with another ternary or similar solution.  But I don't tend to keep track of when features were introduced so some of the others may not be acceptable as well to the OP.

Comment: I think `findFirst().isPresent()` would work in older versions, and then just flip the prints the other way around (not saying to change it just adding more info).  I might be wrong though, I am not the best with streams.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `String.matches` method :

```
String notANum= "ok";
String aNum= "7";
if(notANum.matches("^[0-9]+$") sop("no way!");
if(aNum.matches("^[0-9]+$") sop("yes of course!");
```

The code above would print :

```
yes of course
```

The method accepts a regex, the one in the above exemple is for integers.

**EDIT**

I would use this instead :

```
if(input.matches("^\d+:\d+:\d+$")) success;
else error
```

You don't have to split the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check with nested loop you can see this proposal:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String [] inputString = scanner.nextLine().split(":");

    for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length; i++) {
        String current = inputString[i];
        for (int k = 0; k < current.length(); k++) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(current.charAt(k))) {
                System.out.println("Error");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would you say this is a better solution than the other answers?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make your code better, take a look. You can use Java regex to validate numbers. also defined range for time so no 24:61:61 values is allowed.

```
public class Regex {
    static  boolean range(int timeval,int min,int max)
    {
        boolean status=false;
        if(timeval>=min && timeval<max)
            {status=true;}
        return status;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String regex = "[0-9]{1,2}";
        String input ="23:59:59";
        String msg="please enter valid time ";
        String[] inputString = input.split(":");
        if(inputString[0].matches(regex) && inputString[1].matches(regex) && inputString[2].matches(regex) )
        {
            if(Regex.range(Integer.parseInt(inputString[0]), 00, 24) &&Regex.range(Integer.parseInt(inputString[1]), 00, 60) && Regex.range(Integer.parseInt(inputString[2]), 00, 60))
            {msg="converted time = " + Integer.parseInt(inputString[0]) + " : " +Integer.parseInt(inputString[1])+ " : " +Integer.parseInt(inputString[2]) ;}
        }       
        System.out.println(msg);
}
}
```